# Can print yq output to file

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, stdout

I try to run

```
 echo hello | yq  -r > temp
```

but I get

```
Error: write /dev/stdout: permission denied
```

When I run

```
 echo $(echo hello | yq  -r) > temp
```

It works fine

I can't understand why I can't use that.
For example, this command works fine too

```
echo hello | grep hello > temp
```

qy version

```
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.26.1
```

I have Ubuntu

```
5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Which reasons can be for permission denied?

Comment: a work around I found is the following:  yq -P '.'  your_file.json -oy | grep '' >  your_file.yaml